# Why using external "tr" command on lines with Farsi numbers does not work correctly?

Tags: external-command, unicode

I want to use external `tr` command on a line in `Vim`. When the source or replace pattern includes Farsi numbers the result is unpredictable.

- Executing `:.!tr 1 ۱` on `1` results:

  ```
  Û
  ```
- Executing `:.!tr ۱ 1` on `۱` results:

  ```
  11
  ```
- Executing `:.!tr 12345 ۱۲۳۴۵` on `12345` results:

  ```
  Û±Û²Û
  ```

The `tr` command works correctly in the shell with those parameters. How can I fix this (if it is not a bug)?

This is the output of `vim --version` on my OS X 10.11.4:

```
 $ vim --version
 VIM - Vi IMproved 7.4 (2013 Aug 10, compiled Apr 22 2016 04:36:23)
 MacOS X (unix) version
 Included patches: 1-1755
 Compiled by Homebrew
 Huge version without GUI.  Features included (+) or not (-):
 +acl             +farsi           +mouse_netterm   +tag_binary
 +arabic          +file_in_path    +mouse_sgr       +tag_old_static
 +autocmd         +find_in_path    -mouse_sysmouse  -tag_any_white
 -balloon_eval    +float           +mouse_urxvt     -tcl
 -browse          +folding         +mouse_xterm     +terminfo
 ++builtin_terms  -footer          +multi_byte      +termresponse
 +byte_offset     +fork()          +multi_lang      +textobjects
 +channel         -gettext         -mzscheme        +timers
 +cindent         -hangul_input    +netbeans_intg   +title
 -clientserver    +iconv           +packages        -toolbar
 +clipboard       +insert_expand   +path_extra      +user_commands
 +cmdline_compl   +job             +perl            +vertsplit
 +cmdline_hist    +jumplist        +persistent_undo +virtualedit
 +cmdline_info    +keymap          +postscript      +visual
 +comments        +langmap         +printer         +visualextra
 +conceal         +libcall         +profile         +viminfo
 +cryptv          +linebreak       +python          +vreplace
 +cscope          +lispindent      -python3         +wildignore
 +cursorbind      +listcmds        +quickfix        +wildmenu
 +cursorshape     +localmap        +reltime         +windows
 +dialog_con      -lua             +rightleft       +writebackup
 +diff            +menu            +ruby            -X11
 +digraphs        +mksession       +scrollbind      -xfontset
 -dnd             +modify_fname    +signs           -xim
 -ebcdic          +mouse           +smartindent     -xsmp
 +emacs_tags      -mouseshape      +startuptime     -xterm_clipboard
 +eval            +mouse_dec       +statusline      -xterm_save
 +ex_extra        -mouse_gpm       -sun_workshop    -xpm
 +extra_search    -mouse_jsbterm   +syntax
    system vimrc file: "$VIM/vimrc"
      user vimrc file: "$HOME/.vimrc"
  2nd user vimrc file: "~/.vim/vimrc"
       user exrc file: "$HOME/.exrc"
   fall-back for $VIM: "/usr/local/share/vim"
 Compilation: /usr/bin/clang -c -I. -Iproto -DHAVE_CONFIG_H   -DMACOS_X_UNIX  -Os -w -pipe -march=native -mmacosx-version-min=10.11 -U_FORTIFY_SOURCE -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=1
 Linking: /usr/bin/clang   -L. -L/usr/local/lib -L/usr/local/lib -Wl,-headerpad_max_install_names -o vim        -lm  -lncurses -liconv -framework Cocoa   -fstack-protector  -L/System/Library/Perl/5.18/darwin-thread-multi-2level/CORE -lperl -framework Python   -lruby.2.0.0 -lobjc
```

Comment: How about setting file encoding to utf8?

Comment: What does the following do in your terminal: `echo 1 | tr 1 ۱` ?

Comment: @SibiCoder I have `set encoding=utf-8` setting in my `~/.vimrc`.

Comment: @Nobe4 It works correctly in my terminal. The output is `۱`.

Comment: have a look at http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/farsi.html#Farsi, the part `Setting the Farsi fonts`. Does it help ?

Comment: @Nobe4 Unfortunately I can not find the way to install console fonts is OS X. In addition to this, with previous versions of vim I had no misbehaviors like this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had tried version `7.4.1795` before, but the results was the same. Now I upgraded `vim`:

```
brew upgrade vim
```

In the current version `7.4.1817` the problem is solved.

Thank you all for your comments. This is the output of `vim --version` on my OS X 10.11.4 now:

```
VIM - Vi IMproved 7.4 (2013 Aug 10, compiled May  7 2016 15:14:50)
MacOS X (unix) version
Included patches: 1-1817
Compiled by Homebrew
Huge version without GUI.  Features included (+) or not (-):
+acl             +farsi           +mouse_netterm   +tag_binary
+arabic          +file_in_path    +mouse_sgr       +tag_old_static
+autocmd         +find_in_path    -mouse_sysmouse  -tag_any_white
-balloon_eval    +float           +mouse_urxvt     -tcl
-browse          +folding         +mouse_xterm     +termguicolors
++builtin_terms  -footer          +multi_byte      +terminfo
+byte_offset     +fork()          +multi_lang      +termresponse
+channel         -gettext         -mzscheme        +textobjects
+cindent         -hangul_input    +netbeans_intg   +timers
-clientserver    +iconv           +packages        +title
+clipboard       +insert_expand   +path_extra      -toolbar
+cmdline_compl   +job             +perl            +user_commands
+cmdline_hist    +jumplist        +persistent_undo +vertsplit
+cmdline_info    +keymap          +postscript      +virtualedit
+comments        +langmap         +printer         +visual
+conceal         +libcall         +profile         +visualextra
+cryptv          +linebreak       +python          +viminfo
+cscope          +lispindent      -python3         +vreplace
+cursorbind      +listcmds        +quickfix        +wildignore
+cursorshape     +localmap        +reltime         +wildmenu
+dialog_con      -lua             +rightleft       +windows
+diff            +menu            +ruby            +writebackup
+digraphs        +mksession       +scrollbind      -X11
-dnd             +modify_fname    +signs           -xfontset
-ebcdic          +mouse           +smartindent     -xim
+emacs_tags      -mouseshape      +startuptime     -xsmp
+eval            +mouse_dec       +statusline      -xterm_clipboard
+ex_extra        -mouse_gpm       -sun_workshop    -xterm_save
+extra_search    -mouse_jsbterm   +syntax          -xpm
   system vimrc file: "$VIM/vimrc"
     user vimrc file: "$HOME/.vimrc"
 2nd user vimrc file: "~/.vim/vimrc"
      user exrc file: "$HOME/.exrc"
  fall-back for $VIM: "/usr/local/share/vim"
Compilation: /usr/bin/clang -c -I. -Iproto -DHAVE_CONFIG_H   -F/usr/local/Frameworks -DMACOS_X_UNIX  -Os -w -pipe -march=native -mmacosx-version-min=10.11 -U_FORTIFY_SOURCE -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=1      
Linking: /usr/bin/clang   -L. -L/usr/local/lib -L/usr/local/lib -F/usr/local/Frameworks -Wl,-headerpad_max_install_names -o vim        -lm  -lncurses -liconv -framework Cocoa   -fstack-protector  -L/System/Library/Perl/5.18/darwin-thread-multi-2level/CORE -lperl -framework Python   -lruby.2.0.0 -lobjc
```